# Can not start after upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, password, accounts

I upgraded my system from UbuntuStudio 16.04 to 17.10.

But... Now, when I want to enter to the system (log in) I can not to do it because system doesn't recognize my user account password!

I mean, I see the "Log in" screen, with my user name and waiting for my password, but... When I enter my password... The system goes to blank for 2 seconds and it comes back to the "Log in" screen again!

How can I fix this?

Comment: If your password is unrecognized; you should get an error message (or the box where you enter your password shakes).  If however its accepted, so login proceeds then an issue is detected causing login to fail (usually referred to as login-loop) you won't see this error.  If you have login-loop or can't login from GUI, switch to terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) and try to login there.  That will confirm password is okay, and you can check space (`df -hl`) as if you have no space (esp. in $HOME) login will fail & you'll get login-loop.  Graphics errors & other can apply too.  Please clarify if it's passwd

Comment: Please refer this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop
May be this can help.

Comment: Yes, you're right!!! It is a login-loop. I did [control+alt+F4] and, from the terminal I upgrade from 17.10 top 18.04 and... Now it works so fine, all! So... I guess it is some compatibility issue between 16.04 to 17.10. So... This question is solved!!! Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is useful to all the people who upgraded from  16.04 LTS to 17.10, but... In my case it worked:

1) I enter to the upgraded system (17.10) through  a Terminal [CONTROL+ALT+F4].

2) After I could log in in the terminal session, I type:
    do-release-upgrade

3) Well, here is the Moses Patience Time! It tooked 5 hours, but... The system was full upgraded to 18.04!

Now, all is working so fine, here! I didn't lose anything and I can see all my old Gnome desktop in the same way I had it before the upgrading!

I hope it will be useful to someone!

JUAN